# Pass a Table Type to a Stored Proc from c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I've been using SQL Server 2008 for a while now, yet only today, found out you can create a Table type:

```
CREATE type MyNewTableType as table {
```

And then pass it to a proc.

However, can this functionality be used from within a .Net application (C# is my lang of choice...)? Is it possible to create something within my data access layer, and then pass it as a parameter to my stored procedure?

Comment: Please try passing the table by declaring it as a table variable or as Xml type. You'll find that would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can.  See the section *Configuring a SqlParameter Example* in the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) which will tell you to do something like the following:

```
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.CategoryTableType";
```

The two sections in the MSDN reference following this may also be helpful.

Comment: @FabioGouw According to the most recent MSDN records, it can be a DataTable, DbDataReader, or IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>